# WPF Program Could not Find an Image, and then he didn't find all of them

Tags: c#, wpf, image, uibutton

I am making a game and i have tons of images loaded as content. But when i try and run the game i get that an image was not found. The next time i run the game a different image was not found. i tried going line by line and fixing it but i can't.

I have custom made user controls that have a button on them and i set the background as the image using c#.

```
 public BitmapImage GetBitMapOfImage()
    {
        try
        {
            var a = new BitmapImage(new Uri(String.Format("IMGFolder/{0}.png", this.ToString()), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            return a;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erorr");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

ToString gives a unique name that i gave the file that goes with this object. this BitMapImmage is then used in the next stage:

```
        var brush = new ImageBrush();
        brush.ImageSource =item.GetBitMapOfImage();
        this.item_Button.Background = brush;
        this.item_Button.BeginInit();
        this.item_Button.EndInit();
```

If you can see a problem here tell me because it might not be here, and then i will think on where else the code might be funky.

this is really the first time i am doing a big project in wpf. and the rest i always just gave up.

Thanks!

Final Edit: State: Solved

The Last Image had a different problem that i fixed thanks a lot.

Comment: If you set the image file's Build Action to Content, did you also set Copy to Output Directory?

Answer (score 0):

As someone in the comments mentioned, make sure this setting is on "Copy if newer" or "Copy always".

[image: Properties]

Comment: it still doesn't work for all the Images, check the EDIT.

Comment: Try inserting a breakpoint and watch the variable with the path in it to make sure it's actually getting the desired value.

Comment: i did and i followed the code at its entirety and the problem happened only when it was getting ready to place the Image on screen where that is the code that i don't actually do. There was no problem with my code and i saw that the Image in question was acquired and placed in the right locations and transferred correctly, but when it came time to actually place on the screen the program collapsed. it is looking for the file in the wrong place only when it actually placing it on screen.